# NAS mounted drive permissions as the www folder

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd, permissions

So I am messing around with my Pi (Raspbian) and I have setup an apache server on it with php. I have set the apache server to use a folder on the mounted NAS drive however when trying to use unlink and rename functions I get permission denied. I have set chmod 777 (for all users i believe) on the mount and on the directories i need in the mount but I still get the errors. I know 777 is not the best but just wanted to get it working.

What is the correct way of setting up www-data user up to have full read and write access to the director i need? do I need to set it up on the top level mount and all sub directories or is there a way via the apache config.

I know a little bit of what I am doing, but not enough so it makes me dangerous haha.

Help Appreciated.

Cheers
Mark